# How can I create a custom view other than content types?

Tags: views, 6

How can I create a view that's based on a custom table from a custom module.

Actually in creating views path I can see options of view types as:

> **View type**:
>
> Node: Nodes are a Drupal site's primary content.
>
> Comment: Comments are responses to node content.
>
> File: Files maintained by Drupal and various modules.
>
> Node revision: Node revisions are a history of changes to nodes.
>
> Term: Taxonomy terms are attached to nodes.
>
> User: Users who have created accounts on your site.

But when selecting the node option I can only select from `node table` and selecting user I can select from the `user table` for displaying the data from these tables. But if I need to display data from the custom tables how can I select that table on creating the query and display them on the view pages?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `hook_views_data` to tell Views about your tables and how the data in your tables relates to other tables defined to Views (if it does).  Here's a good tutorial to get you started:
http://www.grasmash.com/article/demystifying-views-api-developers-guide-integrating-views

Depending on the nature of your data, you may, alternatively, consider defining your custom data as a custom entity type.  If you do that through the [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module, then it will provide [Views integration "for free"](https://www.drupal.org/node/1208874).

Comment: How it differ from the hook_theme system ?

Comment: It's similar only in that they're both hooks.  `hook_theme` is a completely separate hook which does totally separate things.

Comment: There is **MODULENAME.views.inc** and i can send the data processed through **hook_views_data()** function , but how clearly it handles the html view  files ? or how can i show data in html files

Comment: Is there any view.tpl.php file specific to a module function ?

Comment: Views tpl suggestions are determined based on a number of factors including the name of the view, name of the display, display plugin used, and a variety of other things.  If you want to provide a general way to customize the look of a view you need to write a display plugin. If you want to override the look of a specific view then your theme can implement an appropriately-named tpl.  I'm confused, though, because none of this has anything to do with exposing your custom tables to Views.

Comment: I need more explanation on the display plugin , i know the second part though. and by default how the views from content types having  a theme suggestions ?

Comment: There's just too much to explain here. Sorry.